# Replacing dots with commas when both are used in the same column in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Col1
4000
2.333.422
1,000,000
0.1
```

As you can see, I have some numbers that use dots as thousand separators and some that use commas. I want to replace the dots with commas, but only if a value has more than one dot in it, so that the last value that uses a dot as a decimal separator, does not get lost.
Any idea how to do this? Much appreciate any help.

Comment: `I want to replace the dots with commas, but only if a value has more than one dot in it`. You mean replace ALL the dots?

Comment: Replacing all the dots for values that have multiple dots in them, like in the second row but not the last row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a combination of `grepl` and `gsub` for a base R option:

```r
x <- c("4000", "2.333.422", "1,000,000", "0.1")
output <- ifelse(grepl("\\..*\\.", x), gsub("\\.", ",", x), x)
output

[1] "4000"      "2,333,422" "1,000,000" "0.1"
```